# Receive Excel Files from FTP Task changing file names everytime

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Im loading excel files from ftp server to SQL Server where ftp server will contain only one file.
There is change of having the file with different name on monthly basis and old file is deleted. At that time if we run the package the package will fails, because ftp server contains new file with new name.

So, how to capture the new file.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use MASK to set the file name for example *.xlsx. 
 Go to FTP Task Editor, set RemotePath to /your ftp path/*.xlsx.

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar. I replaced the File name with the Mask *.*. Its worked.